# How do you mock patch a python class and get a new Mock object for each instantiation?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

OK,
I know this is mentioned in the [manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/), and probably has to do with `side_effect` and/or `return_value`, but a simple, direct example will help me immensely.

I have:

```
class ClassToPatch():
   def __init__(self, *args):
       _do_some_init_stuff()

   def some_func():
       _do_stuff()


class UUT():
    def __init__(self, *args)
       resource_1 = ClassToPatch()
       resource_2 = ClassToPatch()
```

Now, I want to unit test the `UUT` class, and mock the `ClassToPatch`. Knowing the `UUT` class will instantiate exactly two `ClassToPatch` objects, I want the Mock framework to return a new Mock object for each instantiation, so I can later assert calls on each separately.

How do I achieve this using the `@patch` decorator in a test case? Namely, how to fix the following code sample?

```
class TestCase1(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('classToPatch.ClassToPatch',autospec=True)
    def test_1(self,mock1,mock2):
        _assert_stuff()
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's a quick'n'dirty example to get you going:

```
import mock
import unittest

class ClassToPatch():
   def __init__(self, *args):
       pass

   def some_func(self):
       return id(self)

class UUT():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        resource_1 = ClassToPatch()
        resource_2 = ClassToPatch()
        self.test_property = (resource_1.some_func(), resource_2.some_func())

class TestCase1(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('__main__.ClassToPatch', autospec = True)
    def test_1(self, mock1):
        ctpMocks = [mock.Mock(), mock.Mock()]
        ctpMocks[0].some_func.return_value = "funky"
        ctpMocks[1].some_func.return_value = "monkey"
        mock1.side_effect = ctpMocks

        u = UUT()
        self.assertEqual(u.test_property, ("funky", "monkey"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I've added `test_property` to UUT so that the unit test does something useful. Now, without the mock `test_property` should be a tuple containing the ids of the two `ClassToPatch` instances. But with the mock it should be the tuple: `("funky", "monkey")`.

I've used the [`side_effect`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.side_effect) property of the mock object so that a different instance of `ClassToPatch` is returned on each call in the `UUT` initialiser.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** Oh, by the way, when I run the unit test I get:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

OK
```

Comment: (New to Python:) Any way to modify this to work under Python 2.7?

Comment: I just ran this code in Python 2.7.9 (win32) and it worked fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: ~ $ python --version
Python 2.7.5
AttributeError: <module '__main__' from '/home/russ/dev/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.9.0.201411111611/pysrc/runfiles.py'> does not have the attribute 'ClassToPatch'

Comment: @srgerg You're asserting that the mocks were called with the expected calls, but you're not asserting that they were not called with invalid calls. I know that by creating a mock with `Mock(spec=an_object)` then the mock will only accept the same calls as `an_object` but I don't know how to do it when I don't have an instantiated object, such as in this case when the mocks should be the instances of `class ClassToPatch`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another version which is more generic to handle any number of instances created:

```
class TestUUT:
    def test_init(self, mocker):
        class MockedClassToPatchMeta(type):
            static_instance = mocker.MagicMock(spec=ClassToPatch)

            def __getattr__(cls, key):
                return MockedClassToPatchMeta.static_instance.__getattr__(key)

        class MockedClassToPatch(metaclass=MockedClassToPatchMeta):
            original_cls = ClassToPatch
            instances = []

            def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
                MockedClassToPatch.instances.append(
                    mocker.MagicMock(spec=MockedClassToPatch.original_cls))
                MockedClassToPatch.instances[-1].__class__ = MockedClassToPatch
                return MockedClassToPatch.instances[-1]

        mocker.patch(__name__ + '.ClassToPatch', new=MockedClassToPatch)

        UUT()

        # since your original code created two instances
        assert 2 == len(MockedClassToPatch.instances)
```

If you need more thorough validation for each instance you can access `MockedClassToPatch.instances[0]` or `MockedClassToPatch.instances[1]`.

I've also created [a helper library](https://pypi.org/project/mock-generator/) to generate the meta class boilerplate for me. To generate the needed code for your example I wrote:

```
print(PytestMocker(mocked=ClassToPatch, name=__name__).mock_classes().mock_classes_static().generate())
```